# Faulting application issue in NReco PDF conveter

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-8

I created an application which supports html to pdf services. I use NReco PDF Convert sdk for that. It is working well in my local machine but it is not working when I deployed it on live server. When I checked event viewer, the following error is showed.

> Faulting application wkhtmltopdf.exe, version 0.0.0.0, time stamp
>   0x54bd0265, faulting module ntdll.dll, version 6.0.6002.19594, time
>   stamp 0x56ac2982, exception code 0xc0000022, fault offset 0x0006f7b3,
>   process id 0x31d8, application start time 0x01d17b75ca9e33dd.

Anybody know this error?

Answer (score 1):

NReco PdfGenerator is shipped with wkhtmltopdf MSVC 2013 build (which uses VC++ runtime libraries); it works fine in most environments but legacy windows versions might need another MinGW build (it can be downloaded [here](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html) ). I recommend to download it and execute wkhtmltopdf.exe from the command line first to ensure that it is functional.